# Is there a way to use sql functions after using INSERT ALL from a select statement?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-insert, partitioning

I have multiple tables that I am inserting into, and I would like one of the tables to be partitioned after inserting into it so that I can determine the most updated IDs and label their ACTIVE status. My SQL for one of the tables that already contains my data looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE
( 
  LINK_ID BINARY    NOT NULL,
  LOAD         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  SOURCE       STRING    NOT NULL,
  SOURCE_DATE  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ORDER        BIGINT    NOT NULL,
  ID           BINARY    NOT NULL,
  ATTRIBUTE_ID  BINARY    NOT NULL
);

INSERT ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY
      )
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Currently, I am inserting records that show a change in any of the columns to the table. I have extended the table to now include an ACTIVE column and defaulted every record to TRUE for the current records in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD COLUMN ACTIVE BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

When a new record is inserted which indicates a change in one of the column values, I want that ACTIVE value for the new record to be TRUE for that ID group while changing the ACTIVE value for the other records within the ID group to be FALSE (so the previous records would be not considered active/would be FALSE while the most recent record that is inserted indicated by the ORDER value would be active/TRUE)

At first, I tried doing:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY, 
        ACTIVE
      )
SELECT *, OFFSET_NUMBER = MAX(OFFSET_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY O_KEY) AS ACTIVE,
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

However, this does not seem to change the records for each ID group that already exist in the table to false when a new record is inserted that is considered to be the most recent active record. Is there a way I can run this select statement below after all the new records are inserted, but still have it be in the same statement that contains the insertion process?

```
SELECT *, ORDER = MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE,
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: You can use an insert trigger to do that, but assuming you don't intend to query these records often instead of keeping the old records in the original table, it can be better to move them to a separate audit table. This has a column for the table name, a JSON column for the data, and metadata columns such as when the event happened, what event (insert, replace, update, delete), and who made the change. This gives you more information, can be used for any table, potentially can be in a different database, and you can't mistakenly forget the `where status = 'active'`.