# Can we use an insert overwrite after using insert all

Tags: insert, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

In Snowflake I am trying to insert updated records to a table. Then I want to identify the records that were just inserted as the  most recent records save that as the final table output in a new column called ACTIVE which will either be true or flase. I am having an issue incorporating some sort of updated table segment to my current query. I need everything be contained in the same query rather than break it up into separate parts.

I have my table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE
( 
  LINK_ID BINARY    NOT NULL,
  LOAD         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  SOURCE       STRING    NOT NULL,
  SOURCE_DATE  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ORDER        BIGINT    NOT NULL,
  ID           BINARY    NOT NULL,
  ATTRIBUTE_ID  BINARY    NOT NULL
);
```

I have records being inserted in this way:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY
      )
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

I would like my final table from this to be the output as

```
SELECT *, ORDER != MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

This is so I can identify the most recent record per ID group as ACTIVE/TRUE and the previous records within that ID group as INACTIVE/FALSE

I tried to use an insert overwrite method like this

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY
      )
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO MY_TABLE 
  SELECT *, RSRC_OFFSET != MAX(RSRC_OFFSET) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE
  FROM L_OPTION_OPTION_ALLOCATION_TEST
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

However, it seems the insert overwrite doesn't work in this way (also I am not sure if I can just add a new column to the table like this?). Is there a way I can incorporate it into this query or a different way to update the table with this new ACTIVE column within this query itself?

Also I am using INSERT ALL here because I actually have multiple different tables I am inserting into at once, but this is the current table that I am trying to modify.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Is there a way to use sql functions after using INSERT ALL from a select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74978192/is-there-a-way-to-use-sql-functions-after-using-insert-all-from-a-select-stateme)

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to materialize `ACTIVE` column instead of creating a view on top of table and benefit from append-only approach? `CREATE VIEW .. AS SELECT ..., RSRC_OFFSET != MAX(RSRC_OFFSET) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE FROM MY_TABLE;`

Comment: Yes I don't want to create view over this table

Comment: Then you should consider [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) to implemented such logic.

Comment: I have to use INSERT ALL in order to insert into multiple tables at once, using a merge statement would only allow me to pull records into one specified table would it not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overwrite option with conditional multi-table inserts.

Starting with your current statement:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY
      )
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Add the `overwrite` option immediately after the insert command:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE ALL
  WHEN HAS_DATA AND ID_SEQ_NUM > 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = KEY) = 0 THEN
  INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (
        LINK_KEY,
        TIME,
        DATASET_NAME,
        DATASET_DATE,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        O_KEY,
        OA_KEY
      )
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Note that this will truncate and insert ALL tables in the multi-table insert. There is not a way to be selective about which tables get truncated and inserted and which don't.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html#optional-parameters